# UpdatePanel refreshing the whole page instead of the panel content

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, updatepanel

**EDIT:** I have found my issue. I was using this line of code in the page load of my master page :

```
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType(), "fadeAllPartners", "fadeAll();", True)
```

**I have this trouble in my master page contact form and in all the sub page form too.
In fact, I cannot get one update panel work.. 
I also tried to remove the triggers tag but without success.**

**All my page work with a master page which include the script manager here :**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
        <div id="pageWrapper">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Here is one example of a form which refresh the whole page  :**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelContacter" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="submitEmail" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="BodyFooterForm" class="formSubmitEmail">
            <h4>
                <%=Resources.LangueRessources.FooterContactezNous%>
            </h4>        
            <div class="centerFormContact">
                <span id="lblCompany" runat="server"  >
                    <%=Resources.LangueRessources.FooterFormContactCie%>         
                    <b id="imgCompany" runat="server" ></b>
                </span>
                <input runat="server" type="text"  id="txtCompany" >
                <span runat="server" id="lblNom" >
                    <%=Resources.LangueRessources.FooterFormContactNom%>
                    <b id="imgNom" runat="server" ></b>
                </span>
                <input runat="server" type="text" name="txtNom" id="txtNom">
                <span runat="server" id="lblEmail" >
                    <%=Resources.LangueRessources.FooterFormContactEmail%>
                    <b id="imgEmail" runat="server" ></b>
                </span>
                <input runat="server" type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" >
                <span runat="server" id="lblPhone" >
                    <%=Resources.LangueRessources.FooterFormContactPhone%>
                    <b id="imgPhone" runat="server" ></b>
                </span>
                <input runat="server" type="text" name="txtPhone" id="txtPhone" data-mask="(999) 999-9999" >
                <span runat="server" id="lblTextarea" >
                    <%=Resources.langueRessources.FooterFormContactComments%>
                    <b id="imgTextArea" runat="server" ></b>
                </span>
                <textarea runat="server" id="txtTextarea" ></textarea>
                <span id="lblEnvoyer" runat="server" >
                    &nbsp; <b id="imgEnvoyer" runat="server" ></b>  
                </span>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitEmail" class="submit" OnClientClick="return ValidateContactForm()" OnClick="submitEmail_CLick"  />
            </div>      
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

**Thanks !**

Comment: Does it work if you remove `OnClientClick="return ValidateContactForm()"`? Also, could you post the code for `ValidateContactForm()` JavaScript function?

Comment: i have found the issue but i must find another way to fade all my content at load

Comment: Simply using document.ready with my javascript function worked !!

Comment: Glad you found your issue, good luck with your coding! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have found my issue. I was using this line of code in the page load of my master page :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType(), "fadeAllPartners", "fadeAll();", True)
```